# Argument in overriden method with generic return type causes override to fail

Tags: java, generics

I have the following four classes:

```
public interface Account {}

public class SavingsAccount implements Account {}

public abstract class Parent {

    protected abstract <T extends Account> List<T> getAccounts(List<String> ids);
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    protected List<SavingsAccount> getAccounts(List<String> ids) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

}

This produces a compile error on the annotation @Override :

> "method does not override method from its superclass"

If the argument of the method is removed, the compiler does not complain. 
Why does it produce an error in the first place and why does the error go away when the argument is removed?